# How to generate assembly from a cross-compiled binary?

Tags: c, binary, arm, cross-compiling, disassembly

How to generate assembly from a cross-compiled binary?

Compile command used is:

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc test.c -o test
```

How can I disassemble the binary `test`?

I have used:

```
objdump -d test -m arm
```

But it says:

```
test:     file format elf32-little

objdump: can't use supplied machine arm
```

Any help?

Comment: Try `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-objdump`?

Comment: ...or install a multiarch binutils, if you really hate cross-toolchain prefixes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC generates the assembly already, you only need to tell it not to throw the files away when finished:

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -save-temps test.c  -o test
```

Note that the generated files will only contain the assembly language of your code and not the stuff that is linked in from the C libraray, e.g. for `printf()`.

To see the full disassembly including library code, you can use `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-objdump -d test`.

Side note: "test" is a bad example binary name, as there is a binary named `test` already in `/bin/` or `/usr/bin/` on any unix or linux system.